# Where is Route::get() method defined in Laravel-4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am first time using Laravel framework. Trying to read and understand code on my own. I am stuck on one place. Can't find where Route::get() method is defined. Can't find in following classes.

```
laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php
laravel/vendor/symfony/routing/Symfony/Component/Routing/Route.php
```

Curious in which file this method is defined and/or how they are using this method without even defining it. Hope this will help me understanding some advanced OOP feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in

```
Illuminate/Routing/Router.php
```

In your app/config/app.php you should see this alias:

```
'Route'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route',
```

This is the `Route::` (alias class) to the Route facade:

```
Illuminate/Support/Facades/Route.php
```

where it finally points to the IoC binded 'router' instance:

```
$app['router']
```

created by the service provider at

```
Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider.php
```

It's a long path :)

Comment: Thanks. I see a get method in Router class but according to my little knowledge it should be Router::get() instead of Route::get(). Trying to understand whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

What's causing this are the Facades.

[Facade Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/facades) might help you understand it better, but can be a fairly confusing topic.

Comment: Don't only want to find file where it is defined. Want to understand whats going on. Thanks, going to read documentation.

Comment: This should help as well then!  It's a video so it might be easier to follow and it's using Laravel as an example.  https://tutsplus.com/lesson/when-they-say-laravel-shouldnt-use-static-methods/